# A pathological way of passing an array: by reference to the first element

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing

It seems one can pass an array by reference to the first element:

```
void passMe(int& firstElement)
{
    int* p=&firstElement;
    cout << p[0] << p[1];
}
```

Main program:

```
int hat[]={ 5,2,8 };
passMe(hat[0]);
```

Usually, instead of the above function definition, I would do `void passMe(int* myArray)` or `void passMe(int[] myArray)`. But would the method above cause any issues? Knowing the answer would allow me to gain a better understanding of the things at play here, if nothing else.

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are different languages. This is clearly a C++ question so please only use the relevant tag.

Comment: The one issue is that you don't know how many elements make up the array inside the `passMe` function.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the reminder. Yes, `cout` is only admissible in C++, but I tagged C because the main point of the question, in my opinion, is equally applicable to both.

Comment: @FreshAir -- *is equally applicable to both* -- No it isn't.  There is no such thing as a reference parameter in `C`.

Comment: C has no pass by reference. `int& firstElement` is not valid C. The question makes no sense if applied to C.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay, but a common way I see is this prototype `void passMe(int* myArray)`, which would not let me know the size of the array either.

Comment: @FreshAir *but a common way I see is this prototype* -- Written by  poor `C` programmers.  When passed a pointer, it is almost always a given to also pass the number of items, unless there is some contract that the array contains a sentinel or some "stop" value in there that denotes the end of the array.

Comment: @kaylum PaulMcKenzie Okay, I stand corrected about passing by reference. I've approved the tag edit.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, you're absolutely right - in fact, whether the function prototype uses `int* myArray` or `int[] myArray` it is not possible to determine the size of the array. My above method would also need the size to be passed. So I have omitted mentioning size (perhaps a confusing oversimplification on my part) since it was not central to my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as the language-lawyers and the compiler are concerned, it's fine.  The main issue will be with the human programmers (including future versions of yourself).  When your standard C++ programmer sees this in a program:

```
void passMe(int& firstElement);  // function declaration (in a .h file)

int hat[]={ 5,2,8 };
passMe(hat[0]);
```

He is going to expect that passMe() might read and/or modify hat[0].  He is definitely *not* going to expect that passMe() might read and/or modify hat[1].  And when he eventually figures out what you are doing, he's going to be very upset with you for misleading him via unnecessarily "clever" code.  :)

Furthermore, if another programmer (who doesn't know about your trick) tries to call your function from his own code, after seeing only the function declaration in the header, he's likely to try to do something like this:

```
int cane = 5;
passMe(cane);
```

... which will lead directly to mysterious undefined behavior at runtime when passMe() tries to reference the second item in the array after `cane`, which doesn't actually exist because cane is not actually in an array.

Comment: The same logic can be applied to passing the *pointer* to the first element in the array. The only difference is that for variety of mostly historical reasons we are more ready to expect this, compared to passing a reference.

Comment: The one instance where you would readily see the address of the reference that is passed-in being used is the test for self-assignment in many implementations of `operator=`, i.e. `if (this != &rhs)`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is true -- I think the questionable part of the questioner's example isn't the derivation of a pointer from the reference, but rather the application of pointer arithmetic to that pointer afterwards (i.e. making the assumption that the passed-in value will be part of an array, despite the function's signature being one that many/most programmers would assume precludes that assumption)